# Facebook authentication without requesting friend list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-oauth

I'd like to use Facebook OAuth authentication for a web application in a business context. What I need is a user ID and nothing else but Facebook by default always says "... will receive the following info: your friend list and email address".

Is there any way to configure Facebook or my application not to request the friend list for which I have no need to know?

By the way, I am using ASP.NET MVC but should be able to make the required adjustments to my application if someone can point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Microsoft.Asp.net.Facebook** like below tutorial

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-facebook-birthday-app

You can set the attributes like below to get permissions for required things:

```
[FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos", "user_friends")]
```

if you don't need friends details remove the attribute.

```
[FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos")]
```